# Python - retrieve dynamic content using urllib2

Tags: python, urllib2

I am trying to get youtube links embedded in a webpage. When I retrieve the page using urllib2 I don't see the link in the response. I think the embedded video is retrieved by a script on the page which gets loaded when I use a browser. How do I get the same using python's urllib2 ?

A sample webpage is http://busymovies.appspot.com/News.html?id=2965032

Comment: Look at the source. You can see it's not going to be a straight fetch; so then use a tool like Firebug (its Net panel) to look through the requests and responses and look through for YouTube.

Comment: That netpanel is a nice feature. Looks like it is not that straightforward to achieve what I want using just urllib2

Comment: if you only care about this case, hunt through until you find the reference, and then parse it from that particular URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To extract dynamically generated (with javascript) content you could use [selenium](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from contextlib import closing
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox # pip install selenium

url = "http://busymovies.appspot.com/News.html?id=2965032"

# use firefox to get page with javascript generated content
with closing(Firefox()) as browser:
    browser.get(url)
    link = browser.find_element_by_link_text("Direct Link")
    print link.get_attribute("href")
```

#### Output

```
http://www.youtube.com/v/nLJYkat4HpE&hl=en_US&feature=player_embedded&version=3
```

Answer (score 0):

Right below the video there is a link called "Direct Link". Now if you open the source you'll see its structure.

[image]

All you need to do is parse the HTML & get to this node with `id=directlink`. You could use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/download/2.x/documentation.html) for that. You are all set...

Comment: I can see that using firebug, I want to retrieve it using python from the webpage link

Comment: It's not as easy as that because it's a GWT thing and that element is inserted into the DOM at run time.